# How can I create a blog in a web that I make with HTML and CSS? Do I need WordPress?

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress, blogs

I'm doing a website with HTML and CSS. I'd like to create a blog in one of the web's sections but this is dynamic and I don't know how I can do it.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe, you can use Wordpress in a linked domain for example (a linked (his own) cause you'll need to install Wordpress in a database and set all the configurations in your server).

In language terms, you will need knowledge of php and sql/mysql if you want to achieve this without a tool like Wordpress. There are other ways like Laravel or Rails(Frameworks). but any option implies a learning curve and migrate all the page to your choice.

The best option here for you may be Wordpress, there are a bunch of tools that helps a lot like plugins, but i strongly recommend to take this like the first step to learn something of php and then explore this https://developer.wordpress.org/

This will lead you eventually to do all the page in Wordpress and save time and resources.

A life-saver to understand a little more of Wordpress code and how to migrate all you html code to WP: [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=n3EcEYFgyrQ&t=41s)